# How to encrypt the number one using RSA?

Tags: encryption, public-key-infrastructure, rsa

for example:
if we have public key : (5,221) and private key : (77,221) and we want to encrypt 1:

```
c(m) = (m)^p mod n 
c(m)=(1)^77 mod 21 =1
```

so how to deal with that? is there some work around ?

Comment: Use padding. Details here: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3608/why-is-padding-used-for-rsa-encryption-given-that-it-is-not-a-block-cipher